# Is it possible to have declared functions be run without having to include them

Tags: c++, function

If you are familiar with WebGL, you may know about functions like fract() where they can be called anywhere and are defined elsewhere, and an include is not needed, so I was wondering if I could do something similar in C++, and if it is possible, how would I go about it

Comment: No functions are included by default for you in C++, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function you need to see its prototype (or whole definition). So, if you want to call it, you need to include it.